# convert number (hours) to time (HH:MM) in x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is an example of readings taken in every 15 minutes from 6AM to 10PM.

How do I convert hours to time (HH:MM) in x-axis of ggplot

```
tbl <- tibble(x = seq(6, 22, 0.15),
              y = runif(n = 107))


ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Do you need `tbl %>% mutate(x = as_datetime(hm(x))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels =  "%H:%M")`

Comment: `?scale_x_datetime` if you actually had a `POSIXt` column in your data. I think you need to explain (or figure out) how `x` or `y` are "time" in an hour/minute sense *in general* before trying to plot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may convert the 'x' to `datetime` with `as_datetime` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
tbl %>% 
    mutate(x = as_datetime(hm(x))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
     geom_line() + 
     theme_bw() + 
     scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels =  "%H:%M")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot   ..